# How to manipulate values of a tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, translation

This is different approach to translation of page. It is not meant to be localization.
I created class TransModel which all my ViewModels are inheriting from. 
This class fetches string pairs relevant for current ViewModel from database and stores them in "labels" Dictionary. Key for that pair is the value of string here "User Name" and value is translated value.

```
[Display(Name = "User Name")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Instead of using Html.LabelFor in View I use extension of it call it TransLabelFor

```
 public static MvcHtmlString TransLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,TransModel model)
    {  
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);         
        string trans = "";
        model.labels.TryGetValue(metadata.DisplayName, out trans);
        if (trans == null)
        {
            trans = metadata.DisplayName;
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", metadata.DisplayName, trans)); 
    }
```

Now I want to replace what I return by it. I want the original tag as returned by this:

```
 MvcHtmlString originalTag = System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(html, expression);
```

but with my translation.

Are there any neat ways of doing it instead of string find/replace? I don't like that I have to pass Model around either, any better ideas?

Comment: Could you just show the TransModel class, and one of its implementation (one of your ViewModel inheriting from it) ? Cause I think there's an easier way to go, but I would need more infos...

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus TransModel class is bit irrelevant atm as it's not fully implemented. Currently it doesn't fetch data from database, it only initializes labels as `labels = new Dictionary<string,string>(){{"User Name", "Translated User Name"}}` you should get the idea.

Comment: And  labels is a public Property, I presume ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or "improvement" to your solution (also including reflection, but this will avoid to put TransModel in your helpers)

```
public static IHtmlString TransLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
            var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            var modelType = typeof (TModel);

            var resolvedLabelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText))
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

            var labelProperty = modelType.GetProperty("labels");
            if (labelProperty != null)
            {
                var labels = labelProperty.GetValue(html.ViewData.Model, null) as Dictionary<string, string>;
                if (labels != null && labels.ContainsKey(resolvedLabelText))
                    resolvedLabelText = labels[resolvedLabelText];
            }

            var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
            tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
            tag.SetInnerText(resolvedLabelText);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
        }
```

but this will mean you'll have to change all your `LabelFor` to `TransLableFor` (string replace in all solution) : but at least you don't have to add a "TransModel" during the replacement.

Comment: I like this one better. I do want to use TransLabelFor to distinguish between labels I want to translate. It's bit more fun when translating validation errors too. Btw htmlFieldName is not defined. I'm no good with tags need to read a bit.